# Add a div that is "not solid"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to explain myself as best as possible.

I have a `<div>`, in which I add other `<div>`s which the user can manipulate by dragging and resizing it (for this it uses JQuery libraries).  The problem comes when I add several divs (using append (html)); Let's say that the user drags the first detail of the position that he wants, then a second `<div>` is added. (From here there is a problem.  If the first is divided into coordination 0, 0 and is 50px in height, the second `<div>` appears in the coordinate 0, 51, which is not passed) and places it anywhere else... the second problem (heavier than the first) is that if you resize the first split, the second `<div>` is affected; I explain, if it makes the first `<div>` sea higher, and the second `<div>` moves down, the same when the div becomes shorter.

I explain it with the following images, the `<div>`s are those of the black frame, the colored rectangles are a background image:

As you can see, there are three `<div>`s; The `<div>` on the left was the last to join.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVK4v.png]

If we enlarge that last `<div>` (left), then the other two `<div>`s also scroll down, as if the first `<div>` pushed them although visually they are not in a row:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJO60.png]

I know this has to do that for DOOM they are aligned one next to the other even if they are manipulated with JavaScript, but I would like to know if there is any way (with CSS or whatever) that the `<div>`s will not get in the way, that they will not be "solid", they will collapse or anything that will help me avoid that problem.

Comment: First of all, you have to show your code. That will help people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't include your code, I can only guess.

You should use `position: absolute;` to position the child divs. The parent div should be styled with `position: relative;`

Comment: Yes, that work; very thanks :D